# Is there a reliable (single server) MongoDB alternative?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I like the idea of document databases, especially MongoDB. It allows for faster development as we don't have to adjust database schema's. However MongoDB doesn't support multi-document transactions and doesn't guarantee that modifications get written to disk immediately like normal databases (I know that you can make the time between flushes quite small, but it's still no guarantee).

Most of our projects are not that big that they need things like multi-server environments. So keeping that in mind. Are there any single server MongoDB-like document databases that support multi-document transactions and reliable flushing to disk?

Comment: What do you mean, "written to disk immediately like normal databases"?  It's common for high performance database to use a journal (or Write ahead log) to maximize write consistency while batching write operations. MongoDB has [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/journaling/) and is highly recommended (and the default in 64bit 2.0+). MongoDB doesn't have an option for immediate/forced write to journal though (some DBs do). For MongoDB -- it's configurable from 2-300ms.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. With databases like PostgreSQL if I write something to the database and the transaction succeeded, I'm sure that the data will be there if the machine goes down. MongoDB comes close to this with journaling. But as you notice it doens't guarantee it.

Comment: Yes this is the 'D' in ACID.

Comment: Hmm what few people actually know is that even straight to disk has a delay on it due to how data is actually written by the OS to the disk sectors, in fact if the server goes down suddenly you probably will lose maybe a couple of OPs from SQL

Comment: @Tim - There's an option in Postresql and not a requirement that the WAL be configured for immediate, rather than delayed writes.

Comment: try djondb it's a document store database and basically covers what you're asking, I deleted my post because was seen as "advertising", but actually has the features you're looking for. Just give it a try, it's open source so I'm not selling anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very short answer to your specific (but brief) requirements:

> Are there any single server MongoDB-like document databases that support multi-document transactions and reliable flushing to disk?

1. RavenDB [[1](http://ravendb.net)] provides support for multi-doc transactions [[2](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/transaction-support)]. Unfortunately I don't know it handles durability.
2. CouchDB [[3](http://couchdb.apache.org)] provides durable writes, but no multi-doc transactions
3. RethinkDB [[4](http://www.rethinkdb.com)] provides durable writes, but no multi-doc transactions.

So you might wonder what's different about these 3 solutions? Most of the time is their querying support (I'd say RethinkDB has the most advanced one covering pretty much all types of queries: sub-queries, JOINs, aggregations, etc.), their history (read: production readiness -- here I'd probably say CouchDB is in the lead), their distribution model (you mentioned that's not interesting for you), their licensing (RavenDB: commercial, CouchDB: Apache License, Rethinkdb: AGPL).

The next step would be for you to briefly look over their feature set and figure out which one comes close to your needs and give it a try.

Comment: Eventually consistent techs like couchdb do not provide durable writes, it in facts breaks durability. Unless they have a method for ensuring immediate write to disk and immediate replication

Comment: @Sammaye CouchDB is a single server database. It allows you to set up master-master replication but that's a different story. CouchDB writes to disk before acknowledging an operation. Eventually consistency has very little to do with durability per se: basically a synchronously replicated database can be non-durable.

Comment: Strange I read this page: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/performance.html whereby it says: ..."buffers store data in memory before committing it to disk to ensure a higher data throughput. In the event of a power loss or crash (of hard- or software), the data is gone."... and last time I checked immediate replication is a requirement for true durability outside of single server setups, I am also unsure what you men by it being a single sever database, I am fairly certain couchdb can be setup in a cluster: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/clustering.html

Comment: Ignore the edited part of my last comment, I read wrong, but the reference to the couchdb site still stands

Comment: I didn't know the default was changed. But you can still enable it. For reference @Sammaye refers to this paragraph: "Delayed commit (along with sequential UUIDs) is probably the most important CouchDB configuration setting for performance. When it is set to true (the default), CouchDB allows operations to be run against the disk without an explicit fsync after each operation"

Comment: Regarding RavenDB - it *does* perform durable writes.  Store and Load are ACID transactions.

Answer (score 10):

It might be worthwhile to look at [ArangoDB](http://www.arangodb.org/). It is a multi model database with a flexible data model for documents, graphs, and key-values. With respect to your specific requirements, ArangoDB database has full ACID transactions which can span over multiple documents in the same collection as well as over multiple collections (see [Transactions in ArangoDB](http://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/Transactions.html)). That is, you can execute a group of manipulations to your documents together in a transaction and have guaranteed atomicity and isolation. If you additionally set `waitForSync: true`
(as described further down on said page), you get a guaranteed sync to disk before your transaction reports completion. Note that this happens automatically if your transaction spans multiple collections.

Answer (score 5):

I have some experience with CouchDB and ArangoDB which I can share:

You can run CouchDB with durability turned on (delayed_commits = false) so it will also sync your data to disk. 
However, this is a global setting so it affects all writes. AFAIK you cannot set it on a per-collection level (the CouchDB term for "collection" would be "database").

Regarding multi-document operations: CouchDB has MVCC, so reading multiple documents from the same database provides a consistent result even in the face of parallel writers.
Writing multiple documents to the same database can also be made transactional for special cases, e.g. when using the bulk documents API. 
But there is no way to execute cross-database operations in CouchDB. This is just not intended.

On ArangoDB: in ArangoDB you can turn on immediate syncing to disk on a per-collection level: you can turn it on for collections which you cannot tolerate any data loss in. You can turn immediate syncing off for not-so-important collections for performance reasons. It will then still sync modifications to disk frequently, but not immediately. It provides multi-document and multi-collection transactions.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the following:

1. [arangodb](http://www.arangodb.org/)
2. [rethinkdb](http://www.rethinkdb.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look at Couchbase.

Couchbase can be run single server & you can add nodes later if you want.

Couchbase has memcached integrated so you have fast caching of common data, with a reliable method of writing updates to disk.

They also have a new query language (in development but you can use it now) called NQL ("Nickel") that gives you SQL like access, if that's important to you.

With cross-datacenter replication, you can keep two DBs on different machines or data centers in sync, which is good for having an offsite backup.   This also allows you to add elastic search if you wish to have a full text search engine for those types of queries.

In short, Couchbase is a pretty complete solution, all open source and has intelligent (in my opinion) architecture for addressing the typical problems with distributed databases (e.g.: every document is "owned" by a given node, so all changes go to that node, and then the updates are replicated, this is better, I think, than say Riak where you can have updates go to two nodes and then have to be reconciled.)

You can use Couchbase on one node to run the database for many projects by separating the projects into different buckets.

Answer (score 1):

there are so many nosql databases and definitely its hard to choose one. You will have to come up with proper requirements and know   exactly  what you want.
Following link compared almost all the popular nosql databases 
http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Berkeley DB is one we used. It supports ACID.  It does have transactions, but as to your term "multidocument" applies, I'm not entirely sure. I imagine so long as each database (i.e. individual document) shares the same BDB environment (i.e. where transactions are stored) then maybe that gets what you want.  BDB does have other tradeoffs though. With fully durability and high concurrency, commits are pretty slow.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to: http://www.orientdb.org/

*"OrientDB has the flexibility of the Document databases and the power of the Graph databases to manage relationships. It can work in schema-less mode, schema-full or a mix of both. Supports advanced features such as ACID Transactions, Fast Indexes, Native and SQL queries. It imports and exports documents in JSON. OrientDB uses a new indexing algorithm called MVRB-Tree, derived from the Red-Black Tree and from the B+Tree with benefits of both: fast insertion and ultra fast lookup".*

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to adjust schemas in document data stores, but that does not mean you do not need some sort of schema as you probably want to do something meaningful with your data.  It appears you would like an ACID database.  If you have relational data, and you need transactions with that data, well it sounds very much like you need a relational database.

With "NoSQL" databases like Mongo, you are giving up ACID for features like many writable replicas, sharding, and quick accessing of document data.  Sounds like you do not benefit from that so why take the tradeoff? A lot of people have been doing hybrid approaches lately with PostgreSQL by storing documents in a relational table as blobs of JSON.  With this, you can have the advantage of storing your data as not strictly structured columns where it is not needed.

So if you have multiple documents that you need to be transactional on update, you can column out the keys, and have a column "document" or something where it is simply a blob of JSON where you serialize and deserialize it.  This is not criticizing Mongo or other document stores as a database but it is just not really a good choice for transactional multidocument data.  MarkLogic I believe does ACID over multiple documents too.

I think a lot of people find appeal with mongodb due to the schema-less-ness but I think in the end they get bit by trying to shoehorn a relational model into it.  So as always the DB choice depends on how your data is.

Comment: We already considered a hybrid solution using PostgreSQL. However this doesn't allow for a completely flexible schema as MongoDB does. If we want another indexed column we still have to adjust the schema.

Comment: Not quite. You only need to adjust the schema if you need another column. Indexes can be added and removed as required for the cost of rebuilding them. Don't be afraid to split up your index definitions into logical files for revision-control, and apply them as required (presumably with convenience scripts for clean rebuilds and CI testing)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would take a close look at Solr. The underlying data-layer (Lucene) is by far the most mature of the NoSQL databases, and Solr makes installing, configuring, and integrating a single-host lucene store trivial.

In answer to your question, it supports user-delineated transactions. The read-optimised nature of Lucene can make it unsuitable for many applications, but most of those are well suited to Solr/Lucene+[SQL,Cassandra,CouchDB,RDF] depending on the requirements.

Personally I tend to start with Solr+SQL or Solr+RDF, but I know some people who love the whole NodeJS+CouchDB style, and I am convinced of the value of the flexibility that provides.

The bottom line is that there are enough NoSQL and SQL-extensions out there that care about data integrity to satisfy any requirement you have without you having to compromise you or your users' data.

Comment: When I used solr a few years ago, it wasn't suitable for this kind of use.  It crashed under high commit volume, and commits were slow.  There's been some recent work on NRT but it's still got a ways to go.  See caveats listed here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch

Comment: @FrankFarmer unfortunately the questioner didn't provide details of the 'kind of use' they were putting the system to. I can only assume your case was high-volume small-write. I have run Lucene on low-volume large-write/high-volume large-read projects without any instability issues at all, and haven't found anything better than Lucene for that purpose. The class of applications with a small set of hv-sw data and a large set of lv-lw data is significant, and Solr+? is a good candidate for that.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I believe you really need to check what your requirements are.

Due to the dynamics of how the OS of your server works it is complicated to say that everything "immediately" goes to disk even when you tell it to. certainly I know ACID techs like SQL are vulnerable to partial corruption through unfinished business and losing operations within a specific window when a single server goes down, unfortunately this is one of the problems of using a single server; you have no choice but to accept it.

I should note that a transaction does not ensure that your server will receive the entire data before failure ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction ), I mean what if the server dies part way through a transaction?

You can perform a safe rollback based on constraints with transactions but few databases will provide the ability to continue playing the transaction unless they have already received all necessary data for it (which isn't normally the case), by which time the data might even be stale anyway.

In fact due to the weight of some transactions and the amount of queries performed within them I reckon you might get a greater window of operational loss using transactions than you might from the 60ms write to disk window on MongoDB at times. But of course that depends upon abuse, however, just like stored procedures, this abuse is common place.

Transactions shine on cascading deletes and typical scenarios like transferring money in a bank account, however, cascadable deletes are normally better done (as most sites do) by a cronjob with the application marking the row as deleted (to avoid the rollback of a transaction showing the deleted data back to the user again); this way you can do a lot of stuff to ensure consistency that you cannot in real-time do while the user is using your application.

So you should really question why you need a tech and what it will succeed in doing, atm the brevity of your question tells me your not sure about your requirements completely.

Comment: A crashing MongoDB instance can cause data in the database to corrupt (as in half of the operations to do are executed, since it doesn't support multidocument transactions). As far as I know this isn't possible with PostgreSQL. This is what we need.

Comment: @Tim True it isn't possible if you want your speed to crawl to a point where to won't scale beyond small sites, transactions were only really designed to be used for vital mission critical procedures really.

Comment: @Tim Basically if you use anything but transactions and someone tells you you can't get corruption cos this database can defy the laws of computing is lieing. Even with using transactions there is a small chance the transaction can be corrupted

Comment: @Tim As well...(lol) you gotta remember in the time it would take for a transaction to start and init, mongodb would probably have already written to journal, so even though corruption can occur you can just replay the journal to tie up lose ends. One common scenario I do is use SQL for ACID stuff, where it is vital then I use MongoDb for the rest, it works really well

Comment: @Sammaye Your suggestion that databases avoiding corruption is somehow 'defying the laws of computing' is disingenious. While there are some wicked problems involving interactions between multi-layer caching when using consumer grade hardware, thousands of people have implemented corruption free transaction protocols. That MongoDB hasn't is a problem, and the culture you exhibit here -- a disregard for 4 decades of database theory MongoDB has cultivated -- is as much a problem as its lack of ACID.

Comment: @Recurse So you will say that in any nanosecond that a harddrive can fail that an open file can always be written fully? i.e. part way through a transaction is written to disk (since RAM is voilatile) there is NO chance of corruption on a single server if it dies that nanosecond before the transaction is fully written with all it necessary data?

Comment: @Recurse Btw I have talked, over night, to some one who uses posgreSQL in a bigger setup and yes, they get corruption...less frequently using transactions but still; do

Comment: Yes, I do. For starters take a look at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/philbe/ccontrol.aspx and then at http://lca2007.linux.org.au/talk/278.html. The point of ACID isn't that you won't lose the data you're writing, it's that you never write data that is critical to the consistency of the database. IT IS HARD, which is why only thousands of programmers have done it rather than millions. Postgres is mature enough the smart money is on your friend misconfiguring or misusing it; however, it is possible they have found a bug. But the design of Postgres is Consistent.

Comment: @Recurse Can you find something a little less big? Something that defines how a transaction with partially written headers can rollback etc properly on a failed hardisk? I mean something that quickly but consisely defines that it is physically impossible that a program will never lose any data if something required to produce a rollback isn't fully written? Your first link defines about writing a file to hardisk fully that is on and the MS one is a huge book...

Comment: Unfortunately not off the top of my head, sorry. I learnt from a combination of the early chapters of that book, source-code, various academic papers I found on cite-seer, a couple of chapters from other books borrowed from my local Uni library, my background in computer engineering, conversations with colleagues and other database implementers, along with a small stack of relevant standards (in my case: JTA, CORBA-OTA, XOpen-XTP), and further conversations with various implementers of filesystems and other asssoicated OS-level code.

Comment: @Recurse Well I will look into it, I just find it impossible to garuantee, on a single server, that a file can always be written fully if the hardrive switches off; I just can't understand how the transaction headers required for the program to rollback correctly can always be written even if the drive fails in that operation and even though the dynamics of a transaction make this, as you said, hard it is not impossible and does happen, it goes against all real world experience I have ever had with managing databases etc.

Comment: Sammaye I think you are confusing a guaranteed write with durability. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_(computer_science).  If the transaction is half done and the hard drive switches off, the write should be reported as failed to the caller, and when the system recovers, the transaction log will be read and the transaction will be undone.  And as Recurse says, this is a hard thing so one has to be willing to accept some tradeoffs to get it done.  If data is lost that is reported written and transacted by an intermittent failure it is a bug in a durable system.

Comment: @MichaelPapile That is not what I meant. I understand that the transaction has a consistent fallback, what I mean is when a hard-drive fails in a nanosecond how can you guarantee that the binary file needed to ensure full rollback is complete, of course this is normally done by making 5ms commits to the disk, however there is still a chance of corruption in any system if the system fails in the 5ms it takes to write the transaction specific meta data (5ms was pulled out of some magic hat near me)

Comment: @MichaelPapile Ok lets take another example, Linux; Linux has a transactional fail safe to its filesystem which by your theory, of liked database transactions, should prevent corruption at ANY time. I have witnessed quite a few corrupted Linux images in my time from a unclean shut-down. It is a matter of the computer halting at the right time in order for corruption to occur. If you could mind control your computer to stay up until the end of the needed commit then yes it is fully durable, but until such a day it will not be.

Comment: @MichaelPapile In fact from reading about it it seems the durability of a transaction is probability based. You are more probable to have a server shut-down when you are not committing than vice-versa to such a degree that you have a 90% chance of non-corruption on the average set-up (includes single server). However I am unsure about large set-ups across many data centers in many different regions, probabilities in those areas start to become tricky business. I have to read more about the technical setup of a transaction but this is my impression from light reading.